# Gigolo is to man  as  what is to woman?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, analogy, gender-politics

The *American Heritage<sup>®</sup> Dictionary of the English Language* (Fourth Edition) reads:

> *gigolo*, n. A *man* who has a continuing sexual relationship with and receives financial support from a *woman*.

Is there an English word `[X]` which fits the following definition?

> `[X]`, n. A *woman* who has a continuing sexual relationship with and receives financial support from a *man*.

Comment: Isn't it just "prostitute"? Isn't that assumed to be female?

Comment: As on-topic as this question is, there are too many possible inflammatory answers to be constructive.

Comment: Prostitutes do not have a _continuing_ sexual relationship with and receives financial support from _a_ man.

Comment: Prostitute seems fine to me. See where this link ends up: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gigolo

Comment: Actually, I think the initial premise is wrong. What you describe is a *toy boy*, not a gigolo.

Comment: Related: [What is the male equivalent of “mistress” in formal English](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/49367/what-is-the-male-equivalent-of-mistress-in-formal-english), [“Slut” term for males](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/27718/slt-term-for-males).

Comment: @AndrewLeach Except that *toy boy* (or *boy toy*) does not carry with it the notion of predominantly female clientele that *gigolo* seems to.

Comment: @tchrist Who mentioned clientele? A toy boy has a long-term, older partner, usually (if not exclusively) female. A gigolo, on the other hand, is either a male prostitute or simply a man who sleeps around; but a long-term relationship is actively avoided!

Comment: @Andrew Leach But how could I call them otherwise?

Comment: @AndrewLeach Most “male prostitutes” are sorry sorts servicing other, usually older men. They are often runaways, addicts, or both. No, this is not a pretty picture.

Comment: Many other languages have strong masculine/feminine assocatives of words, which would make since why he would wonder about gender specifics of the word.  It might be good to know what language OP is familiar with.

Comment: Voters to close - I didn't know about the word "Gigolette", and don't think this question should be closed just because of the risk of inflammatory answers. For me (female) the words "Gigolette", "Prostitute" and "Mistress" are very different, and give me additional information with which to have some much-needed arguments with some friends. At the end of the day, language is about the ability to express ourselves, and this question - and the answer - are helping me to do that. Vote to stay open, with thanks.

Comment: @Lunivore: Sorry, but someone has deleted the question on "bachelorette", too. I'm wonder whether this site is really helpful for clarifying doubts on English language!

Comment: @XavierVidalHernández Doh. Dudes, stop that.

Comment: mistress and prostitute are 100% different. Mistress is engaged in a relationship with a person, sex being a part of that relationship. Whereas, prostitute provides sex, and only sex, in exchange for something. But to answer the question, the best I can think of is "sugar baby", i.e. in reference to "sugar daddy". I'd be interested to see how this conversation develops

Comment: @Andrew Leach I just earned the "popular question" badge. To my ear this mean there are no false premises in the question!

Comment: "Popular question" means that it was featured in the cross-site auto-collider and mentions sex. Once those two criteria are met, a question is practically guaranteed to be "popular". It has nothing to do with premises, correct, false, or otherwise.

Comment: It's a good thing you gave the definition you're using and the definition you're looking for, because the analogy in the subject line could also be read as "what is the word for the woman who is keeping a gigolo?".

Comment: Another French word that might fit the bill is *demimondaine* (I must admit I never encountered it in English but a quick search suggests it does exist, with a similar meaning).

Comment: This question received TEN answers!? How can you say  it's not got enough attention in your bounty message? The top three answers total 89 upvotes.  Why is the accepted answer, unsatisfactory now?

Comment: Ack, foolish pride!

Comment: To users who might read this comment, a little back-history.... Ahh back again. Why do have a habit of FORGETTING to award your bounties? This is not your first bounty. It's incredibly infuriating and quite inexplicable to me, considering the site reminds users of the expiry date. Note that the community awarded @Mysti was  only HALF of your FIRST bounty, which you did not award. What guarantee do you offer that this time will be any different. Please, do not bother replying in Italian. This is an English language website.

Comment: I understand Gigolo also as a [Bon Vivant](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bon_vivant) and seducer - someone like Casanova, Don Juan... When thinking of a female pendant with hedonistic and feminine traits I'd also throw in the [Femme fatale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Femme_fatale). Of course there is no link to financial support.

Comment: "Tigress" is sometimes used to refer to a female serial seducer.

Comment: -1 DOWNVOTE from me for not awarding yet another bounty.

Comment: @user60812 "Sugar baby" is kind of a gender neutral version of this concept since there is also "sugar momma".

Answer (score 39, accepted):

There might have been a word to match the definition, once upon a time.

The English took the word *gigolo* from the French in the 1920s.

But the word was rather recent in the French language at the time. It had appeared in French, together with its feminine equivalent *gigolette*, in the middle of the 19<sup>th</sup> century.

What’s interesting is that there are two suspected origins to the words *gigolo* and *gigolette* in French. One of them is that both words derive from the Old English word *giglet* or *giglot*, which the OED defines as:

> † a.  Originally, a lewd, wanton woman (*obs*.).
>      b.  A giddy, laughing, romping girl.

Comment: +1 one for interesting possible derivation from English.

Comment: wow interesting spectrum

Answer (score 61):

There is "mistress".

> `7.` A woman other than his wife with whom a man has a long-lasting sexual relationship.  [OED]

Also "kept woman".

Comment: I think 'mistress' is the most parallel.

Comment: @coleopterist, I wonder what that suggests about the society we live in. :P

Comment: Woah.  I didn't know there was a "populist" badge...

Comment: mistress doesn't make any sense -1

Answer (score 37):

I believe it would be "kept woman". Take a look at the definition at [Cambridge Dictionary Online](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/kept_2?q=kept%20woman#kept_2__3):

> someone who does not work but is instead given money and a place to live by the person she or he is having a sexual relationship with

It seems to be the closest parallel for a female gigolo. Mistress, on the other hand, does not necessarily receives financial support, even if it may be common.

Comment: See @Gedgar's answer.

Comment: Yes, I saw it. But I disagree with the part he mentions "mistress" for it doesn't necessarily involves money.

Comment: In that case, please expand on this distinction by adding to your answer. That said, mistresses usually _are_ 'kept'. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mistress_(lover).

Comment: thefreedictionary.com defines "mistress" as "A woman who has a continuing sexual relationship with a usually married man who is not her husband and from whom she generally receives material support." I've always understood the idea of mistress to involve financial support.

Comment: @coleopterist: If you read that Wikipedia entry you'll see that the implication of keptness is historical. Today, at least in the U.S., the word *mistress* carries much less, if any, implication of financial support. While *mistress* may still be understood by some to mean *kept woman*, why not just be explicit and say *kept woman*?

Answer (score 23):

You might consider *concubine*, *courtesan*, or even *châtelaine* more suitable for a longtime *paramour* than the simple *harlot* or *streetwalker* implies.

Comment: *Courtesan* is a good suggestion. *Châtelaine*, however, means 'mistress of the house', or even 'lady of the manor'; not so good.

Comment: @tchrist I agree with the first two suggestions but would you please provide some elaboration or references to go alongside the references?

Comment: the online Merriam Webster dictionary, for 'courtesan', has: "a woman who has sex with rich or important men in exchange for money : a prostitute who has sex with wealthy and powerful men"

Comment: In French, at least, 'gigolo' is not really derogatory, and neither is 'courtisane': both (like to think they) have style, are not simple prostitutes. I feel that the status of a 'gigolo' and of a 'courtesan' are closest.

Answer (score 13):

Because of the asymmetry of relations between men and women, there are few real world instances of a conceptual counterpart to 'gigolo' that is female. And though this doesn't imply necessity, there is no word in English that captures this concept.

The closest thing you can come up with is the compound 'female gigolo', which sounds a bit incongruous given that, while there are many words for women that are not exact counterparts to 'gigolo', they are in the general area. Any possible counterparts are either too general or too specific. (e.g. 'concubine', which I find the closest, has too many connotations of class, monetary situation, legality, cultural and religious association).

Comment: +1 for highlighting the real-world asymmetry of gender relations. Maybe the asymmetry is slowly decreasing, but it is very far from gone.

Answer (score 11):

"Gold Digger" is the term that comes to mind for me if slang is acceptable.  The similarities are that a gold digger can be assumed to be an attractive female who can change men at will, and chooses to stay with whoever spends the most on her.  Not a prostitute, but a fair weather companion more or less.

I think this fits better than kept woman or mistress because in those two situations the woman is considered to be more attached and long term of a partner, with a clear goal of obtaining financial benefit from the relationship. Kept woman has the implication that the male is arranging the situation, while a mistress isn't necessarily financially motivated.

The Kanye West song of the same name explains it pretty well too. :-)

Comment: +1 for encourgement of enriching oneself with Kanye West.

Comment: I think the implication of "gold digger" is that her motivation is *covert*.  She pretends to be in a emotional relationship to exploit her lover economically.  With "kept women", the financial nature of the relationship is overt and agreed-to.

Comment: A gold digger is looking to make money out of someone, a gigolo would at least want the fee agreed up-front.

Answer (score 11):

I'm surprised nobody's mentioned the term "sugar baby", although you won't find that in any heritage dictionaries. It has many results on UrbanDictionary.com though:

- http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=sugar+baby

It has the counterpart word "sugar daddy" to refer to the man who is providing the "financial support". I suspect you're curious, rather than personally interested, but either way, here's some general career advice for aspiring sugar babies:

- http://www.sheknows.com/love-and-sex/articles/838573/5-rules-for-aspiring-sugar-babies

Answer (score 8):

What about an **Escort** ?

Female “**companions**” come in all shapes, sizes and prices. 
However, the ones we hear about the most are the high class **escorts** who make an incredible living being the recipients of both cash and prizes.

In fact, in many instances, these **Escorts** make as much as some of the traders on Wall Street.

Another dictionary reference for **Gigolette**  : A woman who seeks the company and support of rich, older men.

Answer (score 7):

A **gigolette** is mentioned [here](http://dictionary.reverso.net/french-synonyms/gigolette), but I cannot find the reference in English dictionaries.

Comment: You won't find it in an English dictionary. You are giving a link to a **French Thesaurus**, not to a translation dictionary. And it says the word is obsolete, and I confirm it is very obsolete and would not be understood as the feminine form of gigolo by most French people.

Comment: *Gigolo and Gigolette* is the name of a 1935 short story by W. Somerset Maugham.[¹](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W._Somerset_Maugham_bibliography)

Comment: @ΜετάEd: A [short story](http://www.e-reading.org.ua/chapter.php/130321/16/Maugham_-_Selected_Masterpieces.html) that takes place on the French Riveria. The "French touch" in the title is obviously deliberate.

Comment: It is mentioned in the etymology of [Gigolo](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Gigolo) in fifth edition of The American Heritage Dictionary but  it is not an entry of its own, suggesting that it never made the transition over into the English language

Answer (score 4):

Since no one else mentioned it yet, I believe the term *call girl* has many of the same connotations as gigolo but for females.

Answer (score 3):

The word *doxy* has had different implications over its lifetime, but has at times corresponded with *gigolo* pretty well.

Since it's now pretty much obsolete, this is no longer the case.

In all, I'd say *whore* is the best match. It doesn't align very well in terms of nuance, but then that's precisely the nature of the society that gave us gigolos and whores; they **don't** align fairly.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen *hetaira*, plural *hetairai* (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hetaira) used.

Answer (score 2):

Closest term I can think of is Call-girl. It's a prevalent term when it comes to defining a female that is sexually involved for money in return.

Answer (score 1):

**[trophy wife/girlfriend:](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/trophy-wife-girlfriend)** a young, attractive woman who is the partner of a rich and successful older man and acts as a symbol of his social position