# A word for a man who offers his services to have sex with a woman unable to conceive

Tags: single-word-requests, expression-choice

Recently, I read an advert in a local Chinese daily, it read:

> Surrogate father services available for unpregnant, unable to conceive woman: Healthy, medically certified and fit male companion till you achieve a positive pregnancy test.
>   *Free  service with no strings attached- neither emotinal nor financial.
>   Anonymity guaranteed.*

- This guy can not be called a "surrogate father", because he is not going to serve as a father figure.

Another expression could be  *sperm donor* or more specifically, a *sperm bank*. However, the ad does not seem to fit in this category.

[Gigolo](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/77420/gigolo-is-to-man-as-what-is-to-woman) came to mind but since the service is free, it cannot be categorized in the same league as prostitution.

- What can he be called?

  Edit- A natural [inseminator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insemination)?

Comment: "Nice try" comes to mind.

Comment: You could call him a _poor woman's sperm bank_.

Comment: A surrogate mother doesn't serve as a mother figure either. Which means ;surrogate father' really could work. But it just isn't used, you use 'sperm donor'.

Comment: I have trouble with the phrase "unable to conceive woman". If she is unable to conceive (this says it is an inability on her part), then how could this service of 'father's change that?

Comment: @Mitch Judging by the rest of the ad, I don’t think logic and biology is really this guy’s strong suit.

Comment: Wait...is this the start of a Maupassant short story?

Comment: I'd call him a fool, since the claim of 'no strings attached' is legally totally unenforceable.  He could be hit with support payments if he found a taker.

Comment: This is nothing more than a clever ploy to get free sex from multiple women on an ongoing basis- The woman must, by definition, be unable to conceive.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have heard of such ads... we call them **[inseminators](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/inseminator).**

Comment: inseminate doesn't exclusively refer to cattle, nor does it need to.

Comment: the noun's meaning comes from the verb. "inseminator" means "something that inseminates". so one must refer to definitions for "inseminate" to determine what "inseminator" might mean. they're not two unrelated words.

Answer (score 8):

He's not a surrogate father, but he could be considered a **sexual surrogate**, or more specifically a **male sexual surrogate**.

Another common name would be **sperm donor**, although his suggested method of donation inclines one to question his professionalism.

Comment: @thx, sperm donor/surrogate, I contemplated using these words, but these seem to me as misfits.

Comment: _Sexual surrogate_ is already used for another meaning. So it isn't correct for this situation and thus, this answer is misleading. (sometimes called a surrogate partner, is a member of a sex therapy team consisting of client(s), supervising therapist, and surrogate. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexual_surrogate) )

Answer (score 5):

A [stud farm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stud_farm) is utilized in the domain of animal husbandry for the purpose of breeding animals. It says,

> Male animals made available for breeding to outside female animals are said to be "standing at stud", or at "stud service"...

Although *stud* has certain less-desirable connotations, it might be applied in this circumstance.

Answer (score 1):

*A contributor of [genetic material](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/genetic+material)*.<sup>1</sup>

---

<sub>1. You could add *to the [parental](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/parental) project of another*, usually in the context of assisted procreation or reproduction. You could specify *by way of sexual intercourse*. And, finally, *commercial/private*. Certainly not casual but gets the job done!</sub>

Comment: Imho, _inseminator_ has a technical meaning or focus, as I had alluded elsewhere. I think it eschews the parental project which is also a part of this, and adopts the point of view of the action without rendering the contribution. I personally am not a fan of reducing human beings or their activities to bodily functions and using terms such as insertions and latin jargon geared at reproduction, the interest of which lies not in the non idiomatic latin in casual speech but rather in all the science associated with the words. In medical study and research I guess it has its place. Thank you!

Answer (score -2):

What about **one-baby-man.**

Derivation:

If I compare the phrase 'one-night-stand' to your question, it gives me "one-baby-stand".